# IDE HDD + USB to IDE + PSU + AC cable = external HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-supply, adapter, pata

I have couple of 40 pin IDE HDDs which I want to use as external HDDs. Also I have old 300W PSU with AC cable and plan to buy cheap USB to IDE converter like that: 

[image]

I'm not sure if I haven't missed something. Will it work?

Also, is it ok if PSU will be working with green and black wires shortened?

Comment: Typically the IDE->USB converters come with a power brick (like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002) one, for instance) with the needed molex connectors so you don't need to use your own PSU.

Comment: @NathanC I know about that, just don't see any reason to pay 20 times more for same functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As you mentioned, you will need to temporarily short pin 14 (green) to any common wire (black) to turn it on.

Also, since you won't have any sort of case, be careful to not touch or short the circuit board on the underside of the hard drive.

[image]

Comment: Yes you can, but some PSUs are horribly inefficient when below 10-20% of their max rating. A typical 2.5 inch disk is about 6 Watt, a typical 3.5 inch drive might need 15 Watt to spin up and 10 watt to keep working. That is a lot less than the 10% so be prepared to pay relative much for the electricity. If that balances out vs buying a new PSU depends on how much you want to use the drive and the price for eletrical power in your region.